# fputc perfomance and optimization

Tags: c++, c

I have been seeing some strange behavior with a program I wrote that I cannot really explain and I was wondering if anybody could explain to me what is happening here. I have the feeling this is caused by some advanced optimization technique that g++ is using with -O3 but I am not sure.

I am running something similar to this (not a full example):

```
char* str = "(long AB string)"; // string _only_ consisting of As and Bs 
size_t len = strlen(str);
for(unsigned long offset = 0; offset < len; offset++) {
    if(offset % 100 == 0) fputc('\n', f);
    fputc(str[offset], f);
}
```

This is fairly slow. However, when I additionally check the character like this, it suddenly becomes very fast:

```
char* str = "(long AB string)"; // string _only_ consisting of As and Bs 
size_t len = strlen(str);
for(unsigned long offset = 0; offset < len; offset++) {
    if(offset % 100 == 0) fputc('\n', f);
    if(str[offset] != 'A' && str[offset] != 'B') exit(1);
    fputc(str[offset], f);
}
```

This is despite the string only consisting of As and Bs, so the number of characters written does not change and the program always exits normally.

Can anybody explain to me what is happening here? Does the character check allow the optimizer to make some assumptions about str[offset] that it otherwise couldn't make, allowing it to optimize out some part of the fputc call?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with -S and looking at the assembly language?

Comment: I don't get it. Are you asking why your program is finishing early if it exits after the first character that isn't an 'A' or 'B'?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the string only consists of A and B, so this exit(1) call is never actually reached.

Comment: Are you SURE about that? And if you want speed, FGS use putc, not fputc.

Comment: I could imagine that the first version sets up the loop to yield consistently mispredicted branches since the first branch goes the wrong way and that the extra checks cause that to be resolved. Of course, if you wanted fast code you'd actually write sequences of 100 characters at once (`fwrite(str + offset, 1, 100, f)`) followed by a newline. I'd expect that to have a much bigger impact.

Comment: @JimBalter: Yes. I cannot really provide the full code but the program definitely continues normally after the loop. putc instead of fputc is a good suggestion (didn't check the difference so far), but the strange behavior is still there.

Comment: @DietmarKühl There's no advantage to doing fwrite over putc when writing to a buffered stream ... putc will store characters into the buffer and call a flush function when it is full.

Comment: The difference between putc and fputc is solely that the standard allows putc to be implemented as a macro whereas fputc is not.

Comment: if you add the line with the two comparisions, the complete loop is optimized away with -O4...

Comment: @Nils, You should post a complete runnable program that exhibits the problem. Include the input and expected and actual results.

Comment: "Yes." -- How can you say that when the code you provided explicitly prints "(long string)" which does not consist of A's and B's????? C'mon man!

Comment: @JimBalter, @mfro: I realize I wasn't really clear here, sorry. `(long string)` is just a placeholder. In the real code, the contents of str are read from a large file that only contains the characters A/B.

Comment: @Nils Can you post an example input to reproduce this?

Comment: Of course I understand that "(long string)" is just a placeholder -- duh. But the problem is that you're making performance claims and then giving example code that understandably performs much better due to optimization. At the very least provide some timing from your real program using real inputs that supports your claim.

Comment: If you want to know whether its the optomizer, you'll have to post the assembler.  My guess is that A and B are stored in registers in the second one, and that saves a load from memory to register.  But all of that is completely speculation, since you haven't posted the assembler, or even indicated what processor you're on.

Comment: Have you considered inspecting the difference between assembly code dumps?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler optimizes away pretty everything into a simple

```
exit(1)
```

since the compiler is smart enough to recognize the string constant "(long string)" doesn't contain any 'A's or 'B's.

Frankly, I wouldn't have expected gcc to detect that ;)

Comment: I realize I wasn't really clear here, sorry. `(long string)` is just a placeholder. In the real code, the contents of str are read from a large file that only contains the characters A/B.

Comment: @Nils Suggest making sample code more consistent with the question.  `char* str = "(long AB string)";  //  string _only_ consisting of As and Bs`

Answer (score 0):

In C, `fputc(3)` is mandated to be a function; equivalent to the typically implemented as a macro `putc(3)`, which accesses the `FILE` buffer directly. Very hard to do it much faster, except perhaps using `fwrite(3)` to copy a stretch of characters at a time instead of going one-by-one. But such usage is exactly for what `putc(3)` is supposed to be optimized for, so...

Analyze your loop at the base C level by only preprocessing (`gcc -E`) and compiling to assembler (`gcc -S`), that might give some clues.

Are you *sure* (i.e., have concrete measurements to say so) that this loop is performance critical (or even relevant)? That would really be very strange.

Comment: Given the nature of optimisations performed automatically (such as loop hoisting, dead code and unused variable elimination), I wouldn't be surprised if mileage varies from platform to platform.

Comment: According to [C11/7.21.8.2 The `fwrite` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.2), "For each object, size calls are made to the `fputc` function, taking the values (in order) from an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object." I'm not sure how that's supposed to be any faster than "going one-by-one" as you describe, but you might want to investigate [C11/7.21.5.6 The `setvbuf` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6) for future `fputc`-related tests...